# HTML vertical scrollbar is visible only when horizontal scrollbar is on the right

Tags: html, css

I have table from `<div>`s with fixed header. But the table is larger than parent (both vertically and horizontally), so there must be scrollbars. However, vertical scrollbar is visible only when horizontal scrollbar is on the right. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nvt76pok/1/) is fiddle.

Is there any way to "stick" vertical scrollbar to the right edge of parent?

- Vertical scrollbar is only for table body.
- Horizontal scrollbar is for both body and header.
- I cannot use `position: fixed`, because position of table is relative to the page.

[image]

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
}

.table {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
}

.body {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    Header 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    Header 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    Cell 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    Cell 2
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    Cell 3
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    Cell 4
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    Cell 5
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    Cell 6
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth having a look at how bootstrap handle the horizontal scrolling.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#always-responsive

They wrap their tables in a div that allows the entire table to scroll left/right. `<div class="table-responsive"></div>`

See fixed header example here. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/xhao3k9m/

```css
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css";


.container {
  padding: 30px;
}

table {
  width: 150% !important;
  /* test width to make table wider */
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
  display: block;
}

tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

thead th {
  height: 50px;
  /* table header height */
}

tbody {
  height: 120px; /* table height */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

tbody td, thead th {
  width: 50%; /* column widths */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 1</td>
          <td>Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 3</td>
          <td>Cell 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 5</td>
          <td>Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 7</td>
          <td>Cell 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 9</td>
          <td>Cell 10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 11</td>
          <td>Cell 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 13</td>
          <td>Cell 14</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```